# Android Activity choose

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to choose if I should run one activity or another depends on authorization. If you have no account in AccountManager I want to show RegistrationAcitivity in other situation I want to show LoginActivity. What is the best pattern to do that? Where I need to put the code which is checking that? In one of those activities?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the condition is user is already register then move to **AccountManager** .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,AccountManager.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

if not then redirect him to **RegistrationAcitivity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,RegistrationActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

For that you can set flags.

or store data either in **SharedPreferences** or **Database**

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code in Registration Activity, check for accounts there and if available redirect him to login activtiy